# How to change the jenkins home directory location on centos v8?

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins

i installed jenkins on docker via command

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data jenkins/jenkins:lts

I specified the jenkins_home: /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data

but i did not understand why so jenkins it displays :  Home directory /var/jenkins_home

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1lbA.jpg)

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1NOF.jpg)

and what is weird is that this directory (/var/jenkins_home) is empty:

> /var/jenkins_home# ll total 0

This causes me problems with the docker build step

logs:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential git
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/************.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/*************.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials git
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/**************.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 814e24793ed004b24a703ea5ffd79060129e30a4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 814e24793ed004b24a703ea5ffd79060129e30a4 # timeout=10
Commit message: "add jenkins file"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 814e24793ed004b24a703ea5ffd79060129e30a4 # timeout=10
[jenkins-docker-integration] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven381/bin/mvn clean install -DskipTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< fr.startedup:startedup >-----------------------
[INFO] Building startedup 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 29 source files to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target/classes
[INFO] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/src/main/java/fr/startedup/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/src/main/java/fr/startedup/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/src/main/java/fr/startedup/config/apidoc/SwaggerConfiguration.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.8:process-asciidoc (generate-docs) @ startedup ---
[INFO] sourceDirectory /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/src/main/asciidoc does not exist. Skip processing
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:war (default-war) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [startedup] in [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target/startedup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Building war: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target/startedup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.5:repackage (repackage) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ startedup ---
[INFO] Installing /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/target/startedup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/fr/startedup/startedup/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/startedup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration/pom.xml to /var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/fr/startedup/startedup/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/startedup-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.954 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-24T11:48:27Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[jenkins-docker-integration] $ docker build -t startedup01\version88 --pull=true /var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration
ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/jenkins-docker-integration"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:311)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 19 more
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: The right-hand side of the `docker run -v` option is the path inside the container; you probably need this to be `/var/jenkins_home` to match what the preconfigured Jenkins expects.  (You shouldn't directly use `/var/lib/docker/...` paths.)

Comment: Jenkins home is where the code is stored.  You told it where to save it’s data

Comment: I reinstalled and nothing changed (Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure)